# dplyr on Raspberry Pi produces NAs but works on normal machine

Tags: r, dplyr, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I have actually no idea why R produces NAs on my raspberry pi. On my normal machine everything works as expected.

Here is a minimal example to reproduce the problem:

```
library('dplyr')
jnk <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c('a','b','c'))
jnk %>% group_by(b) %>% summarise(a=a)
```

This produces a small data frame looking basically the same.

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
       b     a
  <fctr> <dbl>
1      a     1
2      b     2
3      c     3
```

On my raspberry pi, I get NAs instead of some a

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
       b     a
  <fctr> <dbl>
1      a     1
2      b    NA
3      c    NA
```

I don't know why it works for the first row but not for the others. And, why it is in general not working on the pi.

The output of `sessionInfo` is

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf (32-bit)
Running under: Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=C                 
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8           LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8       
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8      
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8          
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8        LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8     
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bindrcpp_0.2  dplyr_0.7.1   tidyr_0.6.3   mailR_0.4.1   scales_0.4.1 
[6] ggplot2_2.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.11      assertthat_0.2.0  R.methodsS3_1.7.1 R6_2.2.2         
 [5] grid_3.3.3        plyr_1.8.4        gtable_0.2.0      magrittr_1.5     
 [9] rlang_0.1.1       stringi_1.1.5     lazyeval_0.2.0    R.oo_1.21.0      
[13] R.utils_2.5.0     tools_3.3.3       stringr_1.2.0     glue_1.1.1       
[17] munsell_0.4.3     pkgconfig_2.0.1   colorspace_1.3-2  rJava_0.9-8      
[21] bindr_0.1         tibble_1.3.3
```

Comment: Could the use of a period versus a comma as the decimal point be the issue.  R maybe defaulting to the machine's local settings.

Comment: Hm, not sure how to check or change this? `getOption('OutDec')` returns `.` so I guess the setting is correct. Also the first line of the output is correct, and all other things I tested so far seem to be correct. It is just the `summarise(t=temperature, h=humidity)` which seems to make problems.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem in real life, since here I tried to produce a minimal example. Anyway, after searching and asking friends, someone pointed me to this bug report. https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2915 Seems to be a problem in the new `dplyr` version.